# HTTP ERROR 401 and 404 while running Solr search

Tags: solr

I am working on a hybris upgrade to 1808 version. To do this upgrade, i have to upgrade Solr to version 7.4. The upgraded solr server is getting started without any error but when i try to search for any product, it throws HTTP ERROR 401

```html
[m de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.search.FacetSearchException: Error from server at https://localhost:8983/solr: Error from server at https://localhost:8983/solr/master_XXXXXXX_Index: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 401 require authentication</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/master_XXXXXXXX_Index/select. Reason:
<pre>    require authentication</pre></p>
</body>
</html>

        at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.search.impl.LegacyFacetSearchStrategy.search(LegacyFacetSearchStrategy.java:204) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.search.impl.DefaultFacetSearchService.search(DefaultFacetSearchService.java:89) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.search.impl.DefaultFacetSearchService.search(DefaultFacetSearchService.java:78) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.XXXXXX.core.search.content.impl.XXXXXXXXSearchService.quickSearchContent(XXXXXXXXSearchService.java:754) [classes/:?]
```

As i know that this version of solr is using https and security.json for authentication and authorizations, so i removed all authentication related settings i.e. security.json, properties file entry for authType, users and passwords.

```html
[m de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.search.FacetSearchException: Error from server at https://localhost:8983/solr: Error from server at https://localhost:8983/solr/master_XXXXXXXContent_Index: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/master_XXXXXXXContent_Index/select. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
</body>
</html>

        at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.search.impl.LegacyFacetSearchStrategy.search(LegacyFacetSearchStrategy.java:204) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.search.impl.DefaultFacetSearchService.search(DefaultFacetSearchService.java:89) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.search.impl.DefaultFacetSearchService.search(DefaultFacetSearchService.java:78) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.doterra.core.search.content.impl.XXXXXXXXContentSearchService.quickSearchContent(DefaultDoterraContentSearchService.java:754) [classes/:?]
```

I am not sure about what configurations / steps missing which is causing this issue.

Comment: Check the Solr log - are you sure the collections are being started properly after you changed the `security.json` file?

Comment: @MatsLindh - I checked the Solr log and it is showing the same error. Also, please ellaborate on Collection. Did you mean solr cores?

Comment: Any error related to the core or collection being started would be in the server log at startup - not when the request that 404s happens.

Comment: I am not getting any error while server startup in solr log but there are some warnings as  "2019-07-05 18:07:21.457 WARN  (coreLoadExecutor-9-thread-2) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrResourceLoader Solr loaded a deprecated plugin/analysis class [de.hybris.platform.lucene.search.similarities.FixedTFIDFSimilarityFactory]. Please consult documentation how to replace it accordingly."